# Python: logging and TCP handler

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, tcp

I wrote my TCP handler as follows (adapted from: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import SocketServer

from MyModule import myFunction

class MyHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.rfile.readline().strip()
        result = myFunction(self.data)
        self.wfile.write(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = myhost, myport
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

It works perfectly and now I'm trying to add a logger:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import SocketServer
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

from MyModule import myFunction

class MyHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):

    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger()
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        self.formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s :: %(levelname)s :: %(message)s')
        self.file_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler('my_log_file.log', when='D', interval=1, utc=True)
        self.file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        self.file_handler.setFormatter(self.formatter)
        self.logger.addHandler(self.file_handler)

    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.rfile.readline().strip()
        result = myFunction(self.data)
        self.wfile.write(result)

        self.logger.info(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = myhost, myport
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

When I run it I get the following error:

`TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)`

I don't understand what the 4 arguments given are.
Is there anything wrong with the code other than that?

EDIT: Full TraceBack:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('MyIP', 54028)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 290, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 318, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 331, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)
```

Comment: please provide full backtrace. Also, you missed "self." before logger.info(result)

Comment: @MateuszL I added the full backtrace and "self."

Answer (score 2):

`MyHandler` is a subclass of `SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler` which is a subclass of `BaseRequestHandler`. The [call signature of `BaseRequestHandler.__init__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/SocketServer.py#L201) is

```
def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):
```

The traceback error message shows that inside the [`BaseServer.finish_request` method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/SocketServer.py#L329)

```
self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
```

is called. `self.RequestHandlerClass` is `MyHandler`. Therefore,
`MyHandler.__init__` should have call signature

```
class MyHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):
```

instead of

```
class MyHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self):
```

---

When `self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)` is called, Python calls 
the `RequestHandlerClass` method with `self` as its first argument. In other words, 
`RequestHandlerClass(self, request, client_address, self)` gets called. `self, request, client_address, self` are the four arguments that are getting passed to `MyHandler`. 
The error message

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)
```

is complaining that `MyHandler.__init__` was defined to expect only 1 argument and yet it was being passed 4 arguments.